# Do I need to ask permissions to send Push notifications separately, if the user has installed my PWA?

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging, progressive-web-apps

I'm currently exploring PWAs and wondering if it's mandatory to ask separate permission to enable Push notifications to the user who has already installed my PWA. Apps installed from App Store or Play store seem to automatically enable push notifications without asking for separate permission.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/introduction-to-push-notifications#request_permission): "Before we can create a notification we need to get permission from the user." As it says you "need" to get permission, it must be mandatory.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. A PWA is, put very simply, a wrapper around a HTML page. It supplies several bonus features to the website, but at its heart, it's still a HTML5 page. This means that everything a regular webpage does, a PWA also does. This includes asking for permission for whatever thing you want to do, be it notifications, requesting location or capturing video.